# How to delete percent of values in a y_train array with a condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am new to Python and I have a question about deleting 50% of the values in my array y_train, but only the ones with value = 0

So I am using train_test_split to create x_test x_train y_test and y_train. In y_train there is 5287 times the value 0 and 422 times the value 1.
I want to delete 50% of y_train where the value is 0. So that y_train only has 5287/2 = 2644 times value 0 and 422 times value 1.

I want to do this because I have a small dataframe. My random forest model only predict 0 and not 1. So I want a smaller amout of value 0 in the y_train. The problem is that y_train is a array and not a dataframe.

Defining X and Y, with 'Schade_tussen_6_18_mnd' as my target

```
Y = np.array(df['Schade_tussen_6_18_mnd'])
X = df.drop('Schade_tussen_6_18_mnd', axis=1)
```

For splitsing my data:

```
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, stratify=Y)
```

I Tryed this
`Y_train.drop(Y_train.query(' = 0').sample(frac=0.5).index)` 
but I get the error: numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'drop

I expect the output to be y_train(2644 ,422) instead of y_train(5287 ,422)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In practice, don't do this yourself but rather use a package like [imbalanced-learn](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

However here is an example of doing it with numpy:

```
import numpy as np

def make_fake_y(n_zeros, n_ones):
    y = np.array([0]*n_zeros +  [1]*n_ones)
    np.random.shuffle(y)
    return y 

def find_half_the_zeros(y):
    idx_0 = np.where(y==0)[0]
    np.random.shuffle(idx_0)
    idx_delete = idx_0[:idx_0.shape[0]//2]
    return idx_delete
```

example:

```
>> y = make_fake_y(10,5)
>> y
array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0])
>> idx = find_half_the_zeros(y)
>> idx
array([14,  3,  6, 11, 12])
>> np.delete(y,idx)
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1])
```